# dialog become show when press menu in device

Tags: android, dialog

it possible to when i press menu showing the method i have?

i just want to this dialog show and close when i press menu in device
[image: dialog]

this method menuplay

```
private void menuplay(){
       final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this,R.style.Theme_Dialog_costum01);
       dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_play);
       dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_play).setOnTouchListener(
               new OnTouchListener() {
                   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                       dialog.dismiss();
                       //do method
                       return true;
                   }
               });
       dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_highscore).setOnTouchListener(
               new OnTouchListener() {
                   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                       dialog.dismiss();
                       highscoreview();
                       return true;
                   }
               });
       dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_hint).setOnTouchListener(
               new OnTouchListener() {
                   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                       dialog.dismiss();
                       hint();
                       return true;
                   }
               });
       dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_about).setOnTouchListener(
               new OnTouchListener() {
                   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                       dialog.dismiss();
                       aboutview();
                       return true;
                   }
               });
       dialog.show();
   }
```

im trying this one and not work

```
 @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      menuplay();
      return true;
   }
```

Comment: What "menu" do you press? If it´s a button, put your `menuplay()` into the button´s onClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for `Menu Button`

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && event.getAction() == 0 ) 
{
   menuplay();
   return true;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    menuplay();
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```